# Get User Password property

Tags: javascript, user-profile-property, sharepoint-hosted-app, login, password

How to get User Password property to make Log in the applikation in javascript in SharePoint hosted app. I tried to write user.password but i coudent find it. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way you'll ever get access to the users password. (In fact SharePoint don't know it, as Authentication is handles by other components. In fact even these hopefully don't know it, but only have some hash of it).

To access anything in the host web you can use the cross-domain library. Login will be handlede automatically.

See [How to: Access SharePoint 2013 data from apps using the cross-domain library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179927.aspx)